# SharePoint Online access for non-AD and non-live account users

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, authentication, forms-authentication

we are planning to move an on-premises 2010 site to SharePoint Online but we have implemented claims/forms based authentication to provide access to the existing sites and now how can we move or have these users in Office 365/SharePoint Online because SPO supports only either ADFS/AD login or Live/hotmail accounts.

let me know if there are any options with Azure AD or any alternate solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create accounts directly in Azure AD. That would be your only option, besides using Microsoft Accounts. If you create accounts in AAD, you must license them. Any guest users (either Azure B2B or Microsoft Accounts) do not require licensing.

Comment: Do they require email address and self service password management features and how does that effect in terms of cost ?

Comment: SSPR for accounts you've provisioned in Azure AD require an AAD Premium P2 license per user.